# Alter a table column with auto increment by 1 in derby

Tags: sql, database, derby

I have created a table in derby Netbeans and now i realize that i need to make a column as auto incremented by 1 which is a **primary key**. How can i do so? I tried the following code but was in vain.

```
ALTER TABLE ISSUERECIPT ALTER IRCODE SET INCREMENT BY 1;
```

Do i need to create the table once again or can it be possible some other way?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have found an alternate solution, i dropped the column from the database (thanks vels4j) added the column once again from the netbeans derby UI as shown below:

[image]

Comment: This has no effect when I try it (though I don't know to drop a column; can you explain that please?)

Comment: ALTER TABBLE <TABLE NAME> DROP <COLUMN NAME>;

Comment: It doesn't work for me. I can add only the first row (because it's 1 as default) and then I can't add more.

Comment: it would be added on auto increment basis

Comment: Not work for me. Error code -1, SQL state 23505: The statement was aborted because it would have caused a duplicate key value in a unique or primary key constraint or unique index identified by 'SQL141130220816540' defined on 'CUSTOMER'.

Comment: It seems that the "INCREMENT BY 1" has no effect.

Comment: it does not auto increment by 1 in NETBIN 8.0

Answer (score 4):

To alter the column to be auto-generated, the code is

```
ALTER TABLE ISSUERECIPT ALTER IRCODE SET INCREMENT BY 1;
```

BUT the column must already be defined with the IDENTITY attribute (as written in this [documentation](http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.2/ref/rrefsqlj81859.html)).

In most cases (assuming that you too), the primary key column is not set as IDENTITY. Therefore, you may intend to alter the column to IDENTITY, but that is impossible.

The only way is to drop the table and create it again, as written [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7295716).

Answer (score 1):

```
ALTER TABLE ISSUERECIPT  ADD IRCODE INTEGER NOT NULL primary key GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1, INCREMENT BY 1),
```

I guess could do the things for you

Comment: Error code -1, SQL state 42601: ALTER TABLE statement cannot add an IDENTITY column to a table.

Comment: Error code -1, SQL state 42601: ALTER TABLE statement cannot add an IDENTITY column to a table.

Answer (score 1):

Check this

```
ALTER TABLE ISSUERECIPT 
ALTER IRCODE INTEGER NOT NULL 
GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1, INCREMENT BY 1);
```

If your table is empty, Try this

```
ALTER TABLE DROP  PRIMARY KEY your_primaryKeyContrainName ; 
ALTER TABLE ISSUERECIPT DROP COLUMN IRCODE ;
ALTER TABLE ISSUERECIPT ADD COLUMN 
IRCODE PRIMARY KEY INTEGER NOT NULL 
GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1, INCREMENT BY 1);
```

**See Also :** [Derby ALTER TABLE Syntax](http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.1/ref/rrefsqlj81859.html)

Comment: Error code -1, SQL state 42X01: Syntax error: Encountered "INTEGER" at line 2, column 14.

Comment: WHAT ABOUT THE PRIMARY KEY ATTRIBUTE? ITS NOT THERE IN THE QUERY?

Comment: @NiteshVerma *WHAT ABOUT THE PRIMARY KEY ATTRIBUTE?* you didnot mention anything about primary key in your quesiton

Comment: @NiteshVerma check my edit. just drop primary key constraint and add it

Comment: Error code -1, SQL state 42X01: Syntax error: Encountered "" at line 2, column 8.

Answer (score 0):

ALTER TABLE tbl ADD id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT;

Comment: Error code -1, SQL state 42X01: Syntax error: Encountered "AUTO_INCREMENT" at line 1, column 52.

Answer (score 0):

The ALTER TABLE statement cannot add an IDENTITY column to a table

If your table is empty or is not in production. drop table and create again, example:

```
DROP TABLE CUSTOMER;
CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER
(CUSTOMER_ID INTEGER NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1, INCREMENT BY 
1),
FIRSTNAME VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,VARCHAR(100),
PREFERRED_ID INTEGER,
CONSTRAINT primary_key PRIMARY KEY (CUSTOMER_ID)
);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

```
alter table ISSUERECIPT modify column IRCODE int(4) auto_increment
```

Comment: Sorry shows the following error: Error code -1, SQL state 42X01: Syntax error: Encountered "modify" at line 1, column 25.

Comment: Yes. I am sure. You also can make sure : check alter table syntax here. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/alter-table.html. There is modify column option.

Comment: @asmita its not mysql,he is asking for derby

Answer (score -1):

Recreate the table again see example below:

```
CREATE TABLE students
(
id INTEGER NOT NULL GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY (START WITH 1, INCREMENT BY 1),
name VARCHAR(24) NOT NULL,
address VARCHAR(1024),
CONSTRAINT primary_key PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ;
```