# How to auto increment database column in Java derby?

Tags: java, sql, derby, auto-increment

Here's the SQL I've tried so far to create the table

```
CREATE TABLE tblPosts (nId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
strContent VARCHAR(140) NOT NULL,
strLink VARCHAR(200),
strImage VARCHAR(200));
```

using

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO tblPosts VALUES ('" + textFieldContent.getText() + "', '" + 

textFieldLink.getText() + "', '" + textFieldImage.getText() + "')";
```

I get an error telling me I'm not providing the nId column value which I'm not but if the column auto-increments I'm not supposed to right?

I've also tried using the IDE to create the table on the database as described here

[Alter a table column with auto increment by 1 in derby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14316187/alter-a-table-column-with-auto-increment-by-1-in-derby)

Same response though. Any suggestions?

Comment: I would specify the column names in your INSERT command.  Also, I would post the actual error.

Comment: @SteveSmith Thanks Steve.

Comment: Does that mean it worked?

Comment: @SteveSmith Yup. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess that since you're not specifying the column names in the SELECT, it is getting confused as to which columns the data should go in.  I would specify the column names in your INSERT command.

Comment: Apparently I need to wait 6 minutes to mark it as so.

Answer (score 4):

You need to include `Start with 1, Increment by 1`
Like this

```
CREATE TABLE tblPosts (nId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY(Start with 1, Increment by 1), 
strContent VARCHAR(140) NOT NULL, 
strLink VARCHAR(200)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set THAT auto_increment column to DEFAULT like this:

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO tblPosts VALUES ( DEFAULT, '" + textFieldContent.getText() + "', '" + 

textFieldLink.getText() + "', '" + textFieldImage.getText() + "')";
```